# How to denote matrix when writing equation for exam

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-equations

I'm reading an article on Kalman filter on the web: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/integrated3/kleeman_kalman_basics.pdf

Something that I noticed is that bold text is used for both matrix and vectors.

I usually like to use a single right arrow to denote vector, but how do you denote a matrix? Imagine you are writing an exam, how do you let other know that a variable F is a matrix (nxn) but not a vector (vice versa).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capital letters, like $\textbf{A,B,M}$ and so forth are common in representing a matrix. If you are unsure whether or not your notation will be understood, simply state it at the beginning of your solution.

Comment: I agree with this. Make it as clear as possible, e.g. 
"Find $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b  \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have $Ax=b$"
Here you even can skip the bold letters.

Answer (score 2):

In "Further Pure Mathematics, by L.Bostock, S.Chandler and C.Rourke" it says that:

"A particular matrix is described by a bold capital letter $\textbf{A}$, or ($\underline{A}$ when handwritten)"